# Visual Studio 2013 git client - force push

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, git-push, team-explorer

Is it possible to make force push from `Visual Studio 2013` built-in git client?

I know it is possible via command line but I am interested if there is such option in `UI`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Already found the answer myself - No.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286572.aspx#commands

Comment: Heh.  This is quite a significant missing feature in Visual Studio.  They have tons of git functionality yet to implement.  Hope they do so soon.

Comment: Now, only a few years later, they got it in VS2017: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/03/06/new-git-features-in-visual-studio-2017/